# Using Luasec produces "module 'ssl.core' not found"

Tags: linux, ssl, lua

I'm running Lua 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

The version of openssl I have is according to `dpkg -l | grep openssl` is `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.5`.

I have pulled down the source for Luasec 0.5.1

The INSTALL says to run
`lua options.lua -g /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h > options.h` to generate a new options.h against your ssl version.

I've done that and then used `make linux` to build without error.
`sudo make install` then does

```
install -d //usr/share/lua/5.1/ssl //usr/lib/lua/5.1
install -D ssl.so //usr/lib/lua/5.1
install -m644 -D ssl.lua //usr/share/lua/5.1
install -m644 -D https.lua //usr/share/lua/5.1/ssl
```

In my code, I am starting with

```
local socket = require("socket")
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
local ssl = require("ssl")
```

On running this, the ssl line produces:

```
lua: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/ssl.lua:7: module 'ssl.core' not found:
no field package.preload['ssl.core']
no file 'ssl/core.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/ssl/core.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/ssl/core/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/luajit/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta2/ssl/core.lua'
no file './ssl/core.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ssl/core.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
no file './ssl.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ssl.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

There is no `core.lua` I can find in the source. What is it looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssl.core` is defined in `ssl.so`, see `luaopen_ssl_core`.

However, `ssl.so` was installed in `/usr/lib/lua/5.1`, not found in the default paths listed in the error message.

Either move it to `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ssl.so` or change `LUA_CPATH` or `package.cpath` to include `/usr/lib/lua/5.1/`.

INSTALL tells you to adjust `LUAPATH` and `LUACPATH` in the top-level Makefile.